# Is it possible to run android studio software from laptop to desktop using HDMI cable?

Tags: networking, android, hdmi, administrator

I have a laptop having AMD processor for which it restricts to run the android studio in my laptop. I want to run this on my desktop having intel processor using a HDMI cable. Will it work on that?

Kindly suggest or give some idea.

Comment: Why can't you install Android Studio on the desktop?

Comment: @CaldeiraG It's the requirement to work on both platform.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI is multimedia (Video/Audio) interface only and doesn't achieve what you need.

Actually, You can't use External Processor, Even Thunderbolt 3 doesn't support that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your suggestion.